# XCode 6.3 / Swift 1.2 curried functions runtime error in release build?

Tags: function, swift, generics, currying

This little generic function produces an interesting runtime error:

```
func clamps <T: Comparable> (from: T, to: T)(_ x: T) -> T {
    if x < from { return from }
    if x > to { return to }
    return x
}
```

(As I explain below, please keep in mind that I was unable to significantly reduce the error generating code any further – except by removing one of the `if` lines!)

We can use it to generate a `clamp` function like so:

```
let clamp: Int -> Int = clamps(2, 4)
```

We'll print some examples like so:

```
for i in 0...5 {
    println("clamp(\(i)) -> \(clamp(i))")
}
```

When run in Debug the for loop produces the following output:

```
// clamp(0) -> 2
// clamp(1) -> 2
// clamp(2) -> 2
// clamp(3) -> 3
// clamp(4) -> 4
// clamp(5) -> 4
```

Which is what we would expect. When run in Release configuration, however, we get:

```
// clamp(0) -> 4296676200
// clamp(1) -> 4296676200
// clamp(2) -> 4296676200
// clamp(3) -> 4296676200
// clamp(4) -> 4296676200
// clamp(5) -> 4296676200
```

Notice that this number is very close to `UInt32.max` (which is 4294967295), so my guess is that it is some sort of UnicodeScalar value... If you use this `clamps` with other types, like `CGFloat`, the results are similarly nonsensical.

If we rewrite the function so as to avoid Swift's currying syntax, then everything works fine both in Debug and Release:

```
func clamps2 <T: Comparable> (from: T, to: T) -> T -> T {
    return {
        if $0 < from { return from }
        if $0 > to { return to }
        return $0
    }
}

let clamp2: Int -> Int = clamps2(2, 4)

for i in 0...5 {
    println("clamp2(\(i)) -> \(clamp2(i))")
}

// clamp2(0) -> 2
// clamp2(1) -> 2
// clamp2(2) -> 2
// clamp2(3) -> 3
// clamp2(4) -> 4
// clamp2(5) -> 4
```

So the question is whether this really is a bug or have I missed something obvious to the whole world?

As a final example, consider that this (an otherwise useless function) does not reproduce the error:

```
func f <T: Comparable> (from: T, to: T)(_ x: T) -> T {
    if x < from {
        return x // <---- returning x
    }
    return x
}
```

But this does:

```
func f <T: Comparable> (from: T, to: T)(_ x: T) -> T {
    if x < from {
        return from // <---- returning from
    }
    return x
}
```

## Apple Developer Relations response

My bug report just got a message from Apple Developer Relations saying that they believe this issue has been addressed in the latest Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: What would do if you specify the iterator type as `Int`? e.g. `for i: Int in 0..5`? By the way, if there is a difference between Debug and Release, it almost surely a bug.

Comment: "if there is a difference between Debug and Release, it most surely is a bug": that would make a very nice t-shirt! Regarding the explicit iterator type: the same error...

Comment: This is absolutely a bug, you should paste all this into a radar as its very well described.